# How to use traffic data from sumo as an RL environment to be used in python?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, sumo

I am trying to use Reinforcement Learning on Traffic signal controls. I have noticed that I have to set my environment first of all. The problem is that I have the map, vehicles in the junctions and traffic lights set and I need to train my agent to take actions based on this environment and I don't know how to use this traffic data to define my RL environment in python.
I really appreciate it if someone could help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to show us your code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: I don't know how to write my code now cause I figured out from different resources that I need to have my environment specified first and I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have collected the data already then there is no need for an environment. You will be working directly with trajectories - sequences of states, actions and rewards.

For RL you will need a reward signal, do you have this?

If you are asking how to create a simulation environment, there are a number of ways to do this, but it will be somewhat involved. [Here](https://github.com/dicelab-rhul/pystarworlds) is a repository that myself and others from my lab are working on, it is a framework developing agent simulations (include RL simulation environments) in python, although it is still in it infancy (sorry for the shameless self promotion) - we will welcome serious contributions!

For completeness there are other frameworks that exist, the most notable is [gym](https://gym.openai.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. How it is possible? I need to learn my agent attack the traffic light system. How can I do that only with the data itself? I have the vehicles and the traffic light system simulated in Sumo but I need to train my agent how to attack this system. Do you still think I don't need the environment?

Comment: Sorry. Should I generate the data trajectories? and how? What do you mean by reward signal?

Comment: Sorry I think my answer is not useful for you. So you have a simulation, to do reinforcement learning you need a reward signal. Yes, you need to generate trajectories from your simulation. If you are unfamiliar with RL I suggest reading _Reinforcement Learning: an introduction_ it's a great book that covers most of the basics. Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I know what is gonna be my reward function. I am actually not quite familiar with python and generating the trajectory you mentioned. But I do appreciate that.